# arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

Tags: arcpy

Can't share my script as geoprocesing service. 
The warning message: 00068 Script Script contains broken project data source: CURRENT
Here is this part of the script, where the "CURRENT" mapping module is:

```
# get the map document
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
# get the data frame
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"*")[0]
# create a new layer
newlayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer("c:/temperature/result/atlagint.shp")
# add the layer to the map at the top of the TOC in data frame 0
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, newlayer,"TOP")
sourceLayer = "c:/temperature/result/symbology.lyr"
layerSymb = arcpy.mapping.Layer(sourceLayer)  
updateLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "atlagint", df)[0]  
arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(df, updateLayer, layerSymb, "TRUE")  
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add a shapefile to the TOC of ArcMap with `arcpy.mapping.AddLayer()`. This function will only work with .lyr files or map layers already present in an mxd.

In your case, an alternative would be adding the .lyr file first (`sourceLayer`) and replacing its source with `arcpy.mapping.replaceDataSource()`:

```
import os
# get the map document
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
# get the data frame
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"*")[0]

sourceLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer("c:/temperature/result/symbology.lyr")
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, sourceLayer,"TOP")

updateLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[0] 

newlayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer("c:/temperature/result/atlagint.shp")
newlayer_path = os.path.dirname(newlayer)
newlayer_name = os.path.basename(newlayer)

updateLayer.replaceDataSource(newlayer_path, "SHAPEFILE_WORKSPACE", newlayer_name)

arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```