# Add multiple GDB files in subdirectories to mxd using python

Tags: python, arcpy, file-geodatabase

I have GDB files located in many sub-Folders and sub-sub-Folders. All Sub Folders are located in one large directory
i asked it for layer file in
[Add multiple Layer files in subdirectories to mxd using python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130747/add-multiple-layer-files-in-subdirectories-to-mxd-using-python)
I use this code:

```
import arcpy  
import os  

workspace = r"C:\Project\layers"
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Project\Project.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")[0]
walk = arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, datatype="Layer")
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:
    for filename in filenames:
        arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, arcpy.mapping.Layer(os.path.join(dirpath, filename)))
        print filename
    mxd.save()
del mxd
```

How can i do it for GDB files ?

Comment: It's not possible to add a GDB to an mxd... with arcpy you can't even add a feature class. All you can add is a layer. What do you exactly want to do? See [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129547/arcpy-mapping-mapdocumentcurrent/129645#129645) for a possible option.

Comment: @GISGe I agree that it makes no sense to try and add a *.gdb to a map but this Q&A shows how you can add a feature class (shapefile) as a layer: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4882/adding-shapefile-as-layer-in-arcgis-desktop-using-python-arcpy

Comment: @PolyGeo that's true indeed! So the documentation is wrong. Those Layer functions are less restrictive than they should then. Thanks for pointing to this.

Answer (score 1):

So based on @PolyGeo's comment you should just replace the datatype parameter in the `arcpy.da.Walk()` function:

```
walk = arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, datatype="FeatureClass")
```

The rest of the code can be reused as it is.

Comment: the code add all layers in the folder and not just the gdb files