# opening many nested shapefiles

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile

I have a large number of shapefiles (>500) representing species' ranges for North America. I am wondering how I could open them all automatically, without having to open them one at a time in ArcGIS? The shapefiles are nested in a folder for each species, and then in a folder for groups of species by family.

Comment: this answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4882/adding-shapefile-as-layer-in-arcgis-desktop-using-python-arcpy followed by this answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130950/add-multiple-gdb-files-in-subdirectories-to-mxd-using-python/130957#130957 should get you started in the right direction.

Comment: Are you interested in adding the files to the current dataframe or access the files programmatically for some operation like "merge"?

Comment: yes, I would like to be able to merge the files

Comment: also, I am not familiar with Python. Is there some way to do this in ArcGIS using one of the tools?

Answer (score 2):

If all of the data is the same type like polygon, you can try to use arctoolbox to merge them.

```
ArcToolbox -> Data Management toolbox -> General toolset -> Merge
```

There are two method to do merge all of your data including python and arctoolbox.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Merge/001700000055000000/